# React Redux with Redux Observable wait for authentication action to finish before continuing

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

My background is .NET development, WPF precisely. When you wanted to call an authenticated action in C# this is what you roughly have to do.

```
var res = action();
if(res == Not authenticated)
{
  var cred = await showDialog();
  action(cred);
}
```

Pretty simple, call an action, if you are not authenticated show dialog window where user can enter credentials and call action with credentials again.

Now I'm trying to implement the same functionality in redux with epics.

```
export const pullCurrentBranchEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<Action>, store: Store<ApplicationState>) =>
  action$
    .filter(actions.pullCurrentBranch.started.match)
    .mergeMap(action => Observable.merge(
      Observable.of(repoActions.authenticate.started({})),
      waitForActions(action$, repoActions.authenticate.done)
                  .mergeMap(async _=>{
                    const repository = await getCurrentRepository(store.getState());
                    await pullCurrentBranch(repository);
                  })
                  .map(_=>actions.pullCurrentBranch.done({params:{},result:{}}))
                  .race(
                    action$.ofType(repoActions.authenticate.failed.type)
                      .map(() => actions.pullCurrentBranch.failed({error:"User not authenticated",params:{}}))
                      .take(1))
    ));
export const waitForActions = (action$, ...reduxActions) => {
  const actionTypes = reduxActions.map(x => x.type);
  const obs = actionTypes.map(type => action$.ofType(type).take(1));
  return Observable.forkJoin(obs);
};
```

Basically epic will handle an action (I don't even check if user should be authenticated or not because it will double this code) and action will run another action - authenticate.started which will change a state in a reducer to open the window, user will be able to enter his credentials and when he does it, it will call authenticate.done action. When it's done, epic will continue with a promise to call an action which will raise another action when it's finished. Am I doing something wrong? Isn't it just too complicated for such a simple thing? I don't think it's an issue with redux but rather redux observable and epics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might fit your needs. The important thing to note is breaking down the problem into multiple epics.

```
const startAuthEpic = action$ => action$
  .filter(action.pullCurrentBranch.start.match)
  .map(action => repoActions.authenticate.started({});

const authDoneEpic = (action$, store) => action$
  .ofType(repoActions.authenticate.done.type)
  .mergeMap(() => {
    const repo = getCurrentRepository(store.getState());
    return Observable.fromPromise(pullCurrentBranch(repo))
      .map(() => actions.pullCurrentBranch.done({ ... }))
      .catch(error => Observable.of(actions.pullCurrentBranch.failed({ ... })))
  });
```

There are multiple ways to include more authenticated actions, one being:

```
// each new authenticated action would need to fulfill the below contract
const authenticatedActions = [
  {
    action: 'pull',
    match: action.pullCurrentBranch.start.match,
    call: store => {
      const repo = getCurrentRepository(store.getState());
      return pullCurrentBranch(repo);
    },
    onOk: () => actions.pullCurrentBranch.done({}),
    onError: () => actions.pullCurrentBranch.failed({})
  },
  {
    action: 'push',
    match: action.pushCurrentBranch.start.match,
    call: store => {
      const repo = getCurrentRepository(store.getState());
      return pushCurrentBranch(repo);
    },
    onOk: () => actions.pushCurrentBranch.done({}),
    onError: () => actions.pushCurrentBranch.failed({})
  }
];

const startAuthEpic = action$ => action$
  .map(action => ({ action, matched: authenticatedActions.find(a => a.match(action)) }))
  .filter(wrapped => wrapped.matched)
  .map(wrapped => repoActions.authenticate.started({ whenAuthenticated: wrapped.matched }));

const authDoneEpic = (action$, store) => action$
  .ofType(repoActions.authenticated.done.type)
  .pluck('whenAuthenticated')
  .mergeMap(action => {
    const { call, onOk, onError } = action;
    return Observable.fromPromise(call(store))
      .map(onOk)
      .catch(err => Observable.of(onError(err)))
  });
```

You would just have to pass along the `whenAuthenticated` property to the `authenticate.done` action.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. However you can imagine that authenticate will not be done only for pulling but also for pushing. How would you extend your solution to work with both? AuthDoneEpic needs to have an information what action he has to call and what to do if it failed. Would you store it in authenticate.done action payload or where?

Comment: Yes, you would have to include the authenticated action to perform next in the `authenticate.done` payload. I have edited my answer to show one way of doing this.

Comment: Does it mean that I have to store the payload between start and done in the reducer?

Comment: You would in order to pass it to the `authenticate.done` action creator. You might be able to get away with storing only `pull` or `push`, then do a lookup in `authenticatedActions`.